# Build a Table in Wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have to build a table for 5 different teams. The top part of the table has goals they reached and the left side will have each week. At the end of each row there should be a sum of the number of goals they hit for the week, then an overall average. I designed something like this in HTML only right now, but I know a lot of the table should be built in the Java portion. I am not sure how to get it to function either. I am just drawing a blank. Any ideas or helpful links?

Table:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your post seems to have no clear question, as "_Any ideas or helpful links?_" does not qualify as one. Also, you have not shown the effort you have put in to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Wicket's `DataTable` component. With the `columns` array you will define the labels for the headers and how to render each data cell. With `IDataProvider` you will provide the models for the data cells.

See http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/repeater/ for some examples.

Comment: Yes, you will need a POJO.